# Moment.js endOf('month') returning incorrect amount of days for next month

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I'm using moment.js library to get a date. When I set date to a month's end it always returns 30th of that month. But it's not considering that some months have 31 days. How to fix it?

```
case 'currentMonth':
        this.dateTo = moment().endOf('month');
        this.dateFrom = moment().startOf('month');
        break;
```

for example: this.dateTo in the next month (July) will return 30.07.19, but there are 31 days in this month.

Comment: It is June this month, and only has 30 days! I thought I was going crazy then! Unless I'm misunderstanding, are you stating it's only showing 30 days for July?

Comment: It always shows 30 days whatever month. Each month has only 30 day according to moment.js.

Comment: @Messaget https://jsfiddle.net/15tzp7ud/ No, it sounds like it works just as intended: `2019-06-30 2019-06-01 2019-07-31` . Beware of timezones when dealing with date objects, if that's the issue.

Comment: What code are you writing to get 30th july? If you show that in your question we can see what's going on and help.

Comment: Every time you call `moment()` it creates an instance based on current time. So your code above always returns the 30th of June while it is still June.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic use of moment() will default to the current month. In order to get next month (July) you need to add a month to the date.

```
var date = moment().add('months', 1).endOf('month');
```

Comment: Thank you! My mistake was that firstly i added endOf('month') and only after it add('months', 1)